# Converting between string bit and string char out to ASCII

Tags: c#

The problem is to convert non-ASCII characters into binary and vice versa

```
string of bits to string of char
string result = "";
            while (value.Length > 0)
            {   var first8 = value.Substring(0, 8);
                value = value.Substring(8);
                var number = Convert.ToInt64(first8, 2);
                result += (char)number;
```

and 
string of char to string of bits

```
string S = "";
            byte[] asciiBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(value);
            for (int i = 0; i < asciiBytes.Length; i++)
                for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++)
                {
                    S += (asciiBytes[i] & 0x80) > 0 ? "1" : "0";
                    asciiBytes[i] <<= 1;
                }
            return S;
```

Can you correct my code if it is the best?

Comment: for example :bit string ="0011111110110101001111110110111100111111110110110011111101101111"
char string ="?µ?o?Û?o"

Comment: Do you get any errors or are you getting an unexpected output

Comment: What comes first? The string of bits or the array of chars? Or you're the one that has to produce both from some source? This is an importat detail that shouldn't be missing, because the whole procedure depends on this.

Comment: @preciousbetine > the output from my code is unexpected ... if the result from fist code go to input in second code that the output is not equal for input in first code ....

Comment: @Jimi > My working is cryptography ... its This is imperative to me in my work to deal with binary. It must first input is characters in textbox, it is must be change to binary than doing some function to scattering bits then return to characters. But, this end characters must be back to equal input characters if I used the inverse functions. Regards

Comment: Then you should be aware that Cryptography and Encoding need to work together. Since just a small subset of characters can be reproduced using the ASCII Encoding, you probably want to explore the possibility of using the Unicode Encoding to transform your chars in bits (in the form of `string` or `integer` or `boolean`, your choice). Possibly, an Encoding that doesn't vary the number of bits in the CodePoints range you're dealing with. In Windows, it could be `Encoding.Unicode`. Defining what is the correct Encoding to use can be challenging, sometimes. Necessary, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could split the string into 8 character string, convert it to a byte using Convert.ToByte and then use Encoding.ASCII.GetString to convert the byte array to string.

```
var str = "0011111110110101001111110110111100111111110110110011111101101111";
var byteArray = Enumerable.Range(0, str.Length / 8)
        .Select(x => Convert.ToByte(str.Substring(x * 8, 8), 2)).ToArray();
var convertedString = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(byteArray);
```

For 8-Bit

```
Encoding enc = Encoding.GetEncoding(1252);
var convertedString = enc.GetString(byteArray);
```

Output

```
?µ?o?Û?o
```

Comment: thank you. I tried this code but it useless because the ASCII ended in (7E -7bits only-) and not used the extended characters of ASCII that ended in (FF -8bits-)

Comment: This is all ASCII characters:: https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Ascii-codes-table.png

Comment: @seddiq glad to help, kindly mark it as answer/helpful if it helped you resolve your issue.